# c# code filtering a combobox with a paramatized combobox

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I'm writing a program where I add a math-class to sql but use combo boxes for some of the foreign keys so that they can only choose from certain items in a reference table( for example the class names come from a different table with all the class names in. But for some reason the classnameid does not give correct id's when I use the combobox.selectedvalue function. it keeps on giving weird -14 and -25 as id's which is wrong. please help. here is my code

```
    private void btnAddClass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int iclassroomID = Convert.ToInt16(cmbClassRoomName.SelectedValue);
        int iclassTypeID = Convert.ToInt16(cmbClassType.SelectedValue);
        int iHours = Convert.ToInt16(cmbHours.SelectedItem);
        int iMins = Convert.ToInt16(cmbMinutes.SelectedItem);
        string sClassLength = txtLength.Text;
        DateTime dtClassdate;
        dtClassdate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        DateTime myClassDateandTime = dtClassdate.Date.AddHours(iHours).AddMinutes(iMins);
        txtOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(iclassroomID);



        int selectedyear = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Year;
        int selectedmonth = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Month;
        int selectedday = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Day;


        int thisyear = Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Year);
        int thismonth = Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Month);
        int thisday = Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Day);


        if (cmbSchool.SelectedIndex == 0) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select A School");
        }
        else if (cmbClassRoomName.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select A Classroom");
        }
        else if (cmbClassType.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select A Class Type");
        }
        else if (cmbHours.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select the hour for the starting time of the class");
        }
        else if (cmbMinutes.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select the minute for the starting time of the class");
        }
        else if (selectedyear < thisyear)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select a date forward from today");
        }
        else if (selectedmonth < thismonth)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select a date forward from today");
        }
        else if (selectedday < thisday)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select a date forward from today");
        }
        else if (txtLength.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the class length");
        }
        else
        {
            classTableAdapter.AddClass(iclassroomID, iclassTypeID, myClassDateandTime, sClassLength);
            this.Validate();
            this.classBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.geared4MathDataSet);
            MessageBox.Show("Class Added");
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void cmbSchool_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int iclassroomname = Convert.ToInt16(cmbSchool.SelectedValue);

        try
        {
            this.classRoomTableAdapter.FillBySchool(this.geared4MathDataSet.ClassRoom, iclassroomname);
            lblClassroomName.Visible = true;
            cmbClassRoomName.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hScM.jpg
there is my forms. there are 2 uploads on that link. click second page to see the second page

Comment: its the btnaddClass button that is having the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can't see anything obvious that'll break.
Could you provide some sample inputs?
When you debug your code (where you get the -14,-25), are the objects the correct objects?

**Code improvement suggestions:**
Having said that, your variable names are ... lacking ... 
I can understand `cmbClassRoomName`, but all the `iNames` or `dtNames` don't need these prefixes. Also, if you do choose to use the type and the camel case, `iclassTypeID` should be `iClassTypeID`.
Another issue is that the `i`prefix suggests it's an interface, not an int.

About your validation if/else block ... why is it there? Are you using WinForm/WPF/ASP? Have you considered using validations? it might be a bit funny the first time, but it's worth the time to learn in gold later on, decoupling your code so everything makes more sense.

Comment: the if else block is just there to make sure the user does not leave a blank or invalid entry. just part of my error handling. but that works fine, just gives a messagebox if anything is missing.

Comment: I understand what it's for, what I'm saying, is there are other ways of handling it, which are more elegant, and give better feedback to the user. Look [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4445/userfriendly-validation-using-errorprovider/) for example, for the nice exclamation marks. Could you answer the rest of my questions though?

Comment: this is the error i get when i click btnAddClass : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Class__ClassRoom__25869641". The conflict occurred in database "Geared4Math", table "dbo.ClassRoom", column 'ClassRoomID'.
The statement has been terminated. the addclass query is perfect i think. it is a very simple insert function and i use parameter handling to set it up. but it looks like the problem is that my cmbclassroomname.selectedvalue is returning the wrong classroomid:( when i run the program and use the very top textbox(txtoutput)

Comment: just to see what the id is, it doesnt correspond with my id's at all. i have 14 rows in the table data with id's 1-14 but the selectedvalue returns -24 variables for example

Comment: thanks for the link, will definitely use it :) didnt know about it :)

Comment: Cheers, there's a better one somewhere, i'll look for it and update the question later. Are you doing WinForms? WPF?. Also, you're binding the class ID to the class room name, is that supposed to be like that? Did you considered using `SelectedValuePath`? You can have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele) for a quick what's what and how to use it.